# jQuery UI Dialog Functions

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, dialog

I am loading an external php page into a jQuery UI Dialog through the open event like so:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "page.php",
    success: function(data){ 
        $("#loadDiv").dialog({
            open: function(){
                $(this).html(data);
            },
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            minWidth:900,
            minHeight:480,
            modal:true,
            title: "Add Page",
            buttons: {
                "Add": function() {
                    $.post("script.php", $("#addPageForm").serialize() ,
                    function(data){
                        if( data.search("<b>Error</b>") != -1 ||  data.search("<strong>Error</strong>") != -1) {
                            // Error occured 
                        }else{
                            // Success
                        }
                    });
                },
                "Cancel": function(){
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

(#loadDiv is just an empty div that is hidden on the page)

The problem is that when you click the cancel button, it is supposed to close the dialog - but it doesn't. I use FireBug for FF and it tells me the error "$(this).dialog is not a function ... $(this).dialog("close");". When I try to re-open it with $("#loadDiv").dialog("open") doesn't work either and I think the two are related problems.

The problem is that the content of the dialog is being loaded dynamically through ajax, because it works if I take out the ajax part. I need to figure out how to get it to work with the way I am loading the content now.

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the page that I was putting into the dialog included the jQuery source, so I removed that line and it all works fine.

Answer (score 2):

declare your dialog outside the ajax call, set the autoOpen to false. Now inside the success callback, you can then append the data to your empty div, and then just show it. Something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#loadDiv").dialog({            
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            minWidth:900,
            minHeight:480,
            modal:true,
            title: "Add Page",
            buttons: {
                "Add": function() {
                    $.post("script.php", $("#addPageForm").serialize() ,
                    function(data){
                        if( data.search("<b>Error</b>") != -1 ||  data.search("<strong>Error</strong>") != -1) {
                            // Error occured
                        }else{
                            // Success
                        }
                    });
                },
                "Cancel": function(){
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });

});

$.ajax({
    url: "page.php",
    success: function(data){ 
        $('#loadDiv').html(data);
        $('#loadDiv').dialog('open');
    }

});
```

**EDIT** Modified and verified the code with JSLint.

Comment: I did that and I still have the problem with the dialog functions not working. I have a click event that triggers $("#loadDiv").dialog("open"); and it is not working - firebug just tells me it is not a function. When I take the ajax away it all works fine

Comment: do you have the dialog declaration inside document ready? I added a couple of lines. That should work.

Comment: just put it inside the document ready and it still generates the same error message.

Comment: there was a typo in my code on the closing brackets. If you copy and paste, that might be it.

Comment: @Victor: Nope, I just fixed the brackets and its still not working.

Comment: @Key are you sure your ajax is successful? Meaning, is the success callback actually firing? I verified that it works with a successful ajax request. Your ajax must be failing.

Comment: Yes it is because I have the dialog opening inside the success callback - and FireBug is telling me that the open is not a valid function and that only happens when you run it.

Comment: @Key See here: http://jsfiddle.net/DTfEG/1/ You can paste your markup ad modify the ajax call. It works for me.

Comment: @Victor: Figured it out, my page that I was putting into the dialog included the jQuery source, so I removed that line and it all works fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Please check that its not an issue to do with the dialog loading after the document has finished loading, try using live on the click event, and also check if `$(this)` still refers to the dialog.

You may assign a variable to hold a reference to `$(this)` early in your code so that you know that when you are referencing `$(this)` you will be referencing the correct object/element.